# Shifting/Justifying across cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel table with the following formatting:

```
1|     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
2|123 Main Street|   Apartment 1  |  NY, NY 10000   |                 |
3| 17 1st Street |  LA, CA 55555  |                 |                 |
4|  570 Comstock |      Suite 3   |Houston, TX 23123|                 |
5|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
```

I'm looking for a way to "right justify" or shift everything across the cells so it looks like this:

```
1|     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
2|               | 123 Main Street|   Apartment 1   |  NY, NY 10000   |
3|               |                |   17 1st Street |  LA, CA 55555   |
4|               |  570 Comstock  |      Suite 3    |Houston, TX 23123|
5|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
```

Each row has 1-4 columns of data that starts in Line 1. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the addresses (that's what I think those are) is important, I would first insert a column on the extreme left side and put a sequence of numbers down the column. This makes 5 columns (1 'index' column, and 4 columns containing the parts of the addresses).

1.
Sort by `Line 4` to get all the spaces together, like this:

```
1| |     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
5|4|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
2|1|123 Main Street|   Apartment 1  |  NY, NY 10000   |                 |
3|2| 17 1st Street |  LA, CA 55555  |                 |                 |
4|3|  570 Comstock |      Suite 3   |Houston, TX 23123|                 |
```

[Blanks will get at the bottom]

2.
Insert cells before column `Line 1` where the cells in `Line 4` column are empty (that is, for row numbers 3 to 5), so it now becomes like this:

```
1| |     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
2|4|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
3|1|               | 123 Main Street|    Apartment 1  |  NY, NY 10000   |
4|2|               |  17 1st Street |   LA, CA 55555  |                 |
5|3|               |  570 Comstock  |       Suite 3   |Houston, TX23123 |
```

3.
Sort again by `Line 4` so you get something like:

```
1| |     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
2|3|               |  570 Comstock  |       Suite 3   |Houston, TX23123 |
3|4|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
4|1|               | 123 Main Street|    Apartment 1  |  NY, NY 10000   |
5|2|               |  17 1st Street |   LA, CA 55555  |                 |
```

4.
Insert again cells before column `Line 1` where the cells in `Line 4` are empty. (Now, only row number 5).

```
1| |     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
2|3|               |  570 Comstock  |       Suite 3   |Houston, TX23123 |
3|4|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
4|1|               | 123 Main Street|    Apartment 1  |  NY, NY 10000   |
5|2|               |                |  17 1st Street  |   LA, CA 55555  |
```

5.
Now that everything's where it's supposed to be, sort the first column, the `index` we inserted at the very start, which you can delete after sorting.\

```
1| |     Line 1    |     Line 2     |    Line 3       |   Line 4        |
2|1|               | 123 Main Street|    Apartment 1  |  NY, NY 10000   |
3|2|               |                |  17 1st Street  |   LA, CA 55555  |
4|3|               |  570 Comstock  |       Suite 3   |Houston, TX23123 |
5|4|Human Resources|   Building 23  |  Company Lane   |Madison, WI 21311|
```

This doesn't require any formula, since you can get lost sometimes with the brackets and various nested `if`s, and with a few columns, I believe that's actually faster to do! And more efficient than inserting cells one by one at each row.

If the order is not important, just do steps 1 to 4.

Comment: We could say it is an extension of Brad Patton's answer.

Comment: This is a very simple solution for a low number of columns, which this situation was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To shift the cells over select where you want the new cells insert and right-click. From the pop-up menu select `Insert`. Select `Shift cells right` to move them to the right.

[image]

To justify the text highlight the cells and use the `Align Text Right` button in the `Alignment` section.

[image]

Comment: I don't mean justify within the cells. I need to shift them across multiple cells. Let's say one row has only two columns of data (like row 3 does). Instead of Line 3 and Line 4 being blank, I need the data shifted over to those lines. Line 1 and 2 would then become blank.

Comment: Sorry I keyed on the justify part of your question. Updated to handle shifting the cells.

Comment: That works row by row. I have 10000 rows, each with 1-4 columns of data.

Comment: You can select multiple cells and shift them over. I don't know of any other way to selectively move cells.

Answer (score 1):

Messy, but you could achieve it by creating 4 columns next to existing ones and using formulas.

Say Line 1 --> Line 4 is A:D then new columns are E:F

E

```
=IF(ISTEXT($D2),A2,"")
```

F

```
=IF(ISTEXT($D2),B2,IF(ISTEXT($C2),A2,IF(ISTEXT($B2),"")))
```

G

```
=IF(ISTEXT($D2),C2,IF(ISTEXT($C2),B2,IF(ISTEXT($B2),A2,"")))
```

H

```
=IF(ISTEXT($D2),D2,IF(ISTEXT($C2),C2,IF(ISTEXT($B2),B2,IF(ISTEXT($A2),A2,""))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works - and would be quicker to implement if you had a lot of columns.